# Assign daily work entries to contract dates without proper foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables

```
declare @T_Contract as table
(
ID int,
Person_ID int,
ContractDate date
)

insert into @T_Contract
values
(1,1,'2014-01-01') ,
(2,1,'2014-01-03') ,
(3,1,'2015-01-05') ,
(4,1,'2015-03-09')

declare @T_Times as table
(
PersonID int,
StartTime datetime,
EndTime datetime,
EntryDate date
)

insert into @T_Times
values
(1, '10:00', '12:00', '2014-01-01'),
(1, '10:00', '12:00', '2014-01-02'),
(1, '10:00', '12:00', '2014-01-03'),
(1, '10:00', '12:00', '2014-01-04'),
(1, '10:00', '12:00', '2014-01-05'),
(1, '10:00', '12:00', '2014-01-06'),
(1, '10:00', '12:00', '2014-01-07'),
(1, '10:00', '12:00', '2014-01-08'),
(1, '10:00', '12:00', '2014-01-09'),
(1, '10:00', '12:00', '2014-01-10')
```

What I try to acchieve for hours is to get a table where the entries of `@T_Times` occur only for the valid contract. Let me give you an example: The entry on the day `2014-01-02` was made during the contract `1` applied   so it is in the result table only once assigned to the contract

The result table would look like:

```
Person_ID|ContractDate|StartTime|EndTime|EntryDate
1        |2014-01-01  |10:00    |12:00  |2014-01-01
1        |2014-01-01  |10:00    |12:00  |2014-01-02
1        |2014-01-03  |10:00    |12:00  |2014-01-03
1        |2014-01-03  |10:00    |12:00  |2014-01-04
1        |2014-01-05  |10:00    |12:00  |2014-01-05
```

The backbone of my attemps is

If I run the query

```
select * from @T_Times times
left join @T_Contract cont
on times.PersonID = cont.Person_ID
```

I tried to do `contract < entrydate` but this is not working. Another idea was that I use the differences `MIN(Entrydate - (ContractDate))` and check this for each `contract date`. But I do not know how to implement that in `TSQL` and could not found anything. `Group By` did not gave my any satisfying results as well.

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: Your explanation isn't clear. how `the entry on the 2014-01-02 ` was made during entry contract 1? is that entry a `time` ? because contract doesnt have that date.

Comment: Contract 1 has the date 2014-01-01. Since the entry was made before the next contract (2014-01-03) was applied the entries has to be assigned to contract one. I hope that is more clear. I also adjusted my question a bit. I am using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: when you reply to another user add the `@<username>` like this @ruedi so other person get a notification

Comment: Next time please try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza There is no requirement on this site for SQL questions to use SqlFiddle.  Indeed since that site is unaffiliated with SO and we cannot guarantee it's future availability it is important that questions (and answers) ***not*** be dependent on it.  It's OK to use it, but we should be able to read and answer questions without it.

Comment: Please tell us what version of SQL Server this is for as some features (such as `LEAD`) are only available in later versions.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Is just a suggestion as you can read In the `how to ask` page. `If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/`

Comment: I have the sql server 2014 express version.

Comment: Then you can use the lead() function as in my example, let me know if work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use [LEAD()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to see what is the next date and get the close contract. Lead also allow a default in this case `getdate()`

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ded5a/1)

I modify the last 3 rows in your sample data so appear contract on those ranges too.

```
WITH contract_range as (
     SELECT 
       ID ContractID,
       ContractDate, 
       LEAD(ContractDate, 1, GETDATE()) OVER (ORDER BY ContractDate) AS EndContract
     FROM Contract
)
select t.PersonID, cr.ContractID, cr.ContractDate, t.StartTime, t.EndTime, t.EntryDate
from contract_range cr
inner join Times t
   ON t.EntryDate >= cr.ContractDate
   AND t.EntryDate < cr.EndContract
```